# MYSQL count of num users using joins

Tags: mysql

My mysql schema looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+----------+ +---------+-----------+
| user_id | club_id | username | | club_id | club_name |
+---------+---------+----------+ +---------+-----------+
| 1       | 1       | bob      | | 1       | bobcats   |
| 2       | 1       | tom      | | 2       | carguys   |
| 3       | 1       | sam      | +---------+-----------+
| 4       | 2       | mat      |
+---------+---------+----------+
```

I want a select query which returns:

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| club_id | club_name | num_members |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| 1       | bobcats   | 3           |
| 2       | carguys   | 1           |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT clubs.club_id
     , clubs.club_name
     , COUNT(DISTINCT users.club_id) AS num_members 
  FROM users 
  JOIN clubs 
    on users.club_id = clubs.club_id 
 ORDER 
    BY clubs.club_name
```

What I got when I tried that (only the first row and not all of the clubs):

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| club_id | club_name | num_members |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| 1       | bobcats   | 3           |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: You forgot `GROUP BY clubs.club_id`

Comment: Also, `COUNT(DISTINCT users.club_id)` should be `COUNT(*)`. Otherwise all the counts will be `1` because `users.club_id` is the same for all members of the same club.

Comment: I am missing something. Tried this and did not work: SELECT clubs.club_id
     , clubs.club_name
     , COUNT(*) AS num_members 
  FROM users 
  JOIN clubs 
    on users.club_id = clubs.club_id 
 ORDER 
    BY clubs.club_id

Comment: You're still missing `GROUP BY clubs.club_id`

Comment: This is basic SQL, you need to use `GROUP BY` to get per-group aggregation instead of a total for the entire query.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Barmar. My sql is definitely rusty. Appreciate the help